# How to access the last element of an array using destructuring?

Tags: javascript, arrays

Suppose I have an array like this: `[2, 4, 6, 8, 10]`.

I want to access the first and last element of this array using destructuring, currently I'm doing this:

```js
const array = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
const [first, , , , last] = array;
console.log(first, last);
```

But this is only works with arrays of length `5` and is *not* generic enough.

In Python I could do something like this:

```
array = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10]
first, *mid, last = array
print(first, last)
```

But in JS this is not possible since rest elements should be the last. So, is there some way to do this in JS or this is not possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use [object destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment#object_destructuring) and grab the `0` key (*which is the first element*) and rename it to `first` & then using [computed property names](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#new_notations_in_ecmascript_2015) you can grab the `array.length - 1` key (*which is the last element*) and rename it to `last`.

```js
const array = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
const { 0: first, [array.length - 1]: last } = array;
console.log(first, last);
```

You can also grab the `length` via destructuring and then use that to grab the last element.

```js
const array = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
const { length, 0: first, [length - 1]: last } = array;
console.log(first, last);
```

Another simple approach to access the last element would be to use the [Array.prototype.at](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/at) method. This is *not* related to destructuring but it's worth knowing.

```js
const array = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
console.log(array.at(-1));
```

Comment: At which point, you might as well not use destructuring at all.

Comment: @Cerbrus Yeah, but it's good to know that it's possible with JS.

Comment: The `at` method was added in ES2022 (ES23).

Answer (score 2):

Not necessarily using destructuring, but still concise in my opinion:

```js
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
const [ first, last ] = [ arr.at(0), arr.at(-1) ];

console.log(first, last);
```

Comment: You can simply `console.log(arr.at(0), arr.at(-1))`, why unnecessarily create an array and destructure from it?

Comment: @SSM: Because OP probably isn't _just_ destructuring those items to log them. In this case, the array wrapper helps keep the variable declaration in a single line.

Comment: @Cerbrus You can store them in variables, `const first = arr.at(0), last = arr.at(-1)`, there's no point creating an array unnecessarily.

Comment: I don't think you should be criticising the validity of someone's answer when your answering with a convoluted destructuring approach, yourself, @SSM.

Comment: The OP is regarding destructuring and whether it's possible using JS or not? It's *not* about accessing the last element of the array. And I never said the answer is *not* valid, I simply pointed out the unnecessary creation of an array.

Comment: @SSM: Read the question's title again...

Comment: BTW, another alternative would be to simply use a function:
`const getHeadAndTail = arr => ({ first: arr.at(0), last: arr.at(-1) });`

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Could you please add typescript version of it? since I am getting "Type 'number | undefined' is not assignable to type 'number'" error, as "arr.at(0)" sometimes can be undefined as well.

Answer (score -1):

No, you can't use destructuring like that without convoluted workarounds.
A shorter, more readable alternative is to just [`pop`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/pop):

```js
const array = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
const [first, ...middle] = array;
const last = middle.pop();

console.log(first, middle, last);
```

Or, just access them by index:

```js
const array = [2, 4, 6, 8, 10];
const first = array[0];
const last = array[array.length - 1];

console.log(first, last);
```